# type of transformer shown in a document

Tags: transformer, dc-dc-converter

I am designing a dc dc isolated forward converter that accepts 20V and outputs 10V(Imax of 5Amps). As part of the study I was reading this document
[Document](http://www.ivobarbi.com/PDF/GE03-ARBOY-COUSIN-PFE_Rev_MLH.pdf)
In the page 15, it shows a transformer which has the symbol shown below -
[image: Transformer]

What kind of transformer is this ?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by "kind", do you want to know what type the core should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is a a  [Tertiary Winding transformer](http://www.electrical4u.com/tertiary-winding-of-transformer-three-winding-transformer/).
in you [document](http://www.ivobarbi.com/PDF/GE03-ARBOY-COUSIN-PFE_Rev_MLH.pdf) they say: The particularity of the transformer in the forward converter (Figure 9) is that is a third winding, The purpose of the third winding is to assure the function of the complete demagnetization of the transformer at the end of each commutation period of the converter.